# How to go back to a point in time for distro state?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, apt

I'm trying to test a bug fix for a bug that surfaced under Debian about 14 months ago. We believe we [finally] located the cause and cleared the issue. Its no longer present, but the distribution's state today is different than 18 months ago. Neither us nor our Debian package maintainer has access to the config that witnessed the bug.

I know the approximate date of when I need to be based on email discussions. To complicate matters, the issue was only present in an armel chroot. It was not present in common arch's, like i686, x86_64 and armhf. And other less common ones, like S/390 and mips, were OK too.

The package equivalent of what I want to do is checkout a detached head up to a particular commit hash. But instead of doing it for one package, I want to do it for the entire distro, including the chroot guest.

Is it possible to go back to a specific point in time? If so, how do I go back in time for a dpkg/apt based disto like Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that possible *in general* to achieve in a simple way. Lots of repositories abandon support for obsolete builds over time, so that up-to-date builds supersede old ones.

From my experience, this applies to most of major Linux distributions, Debian included.

To reproduce exact environment months back, you should look into Debian packages change log, pulling & rebuilding required revisions from SCM next.